# NSTimer Crashing

Tags: objective-c, nstimer

Thanks for the help. Experimenting with basic progressIndicator animation. This crashes, and noted: "TO8 Generator was compiled with optimization - stepping may behave oddly; variables may not be available." TO8 Generator is obviously the application.

Message:"No known class method for selector 'scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:selector:userInfo:repeats:'

Any insight? Thank you again.

```
NSTimer *timer;
int count;  

if(!timer)
{
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01
                                             target:self
                                           selector:@selector(checkThem:)
                                           userInfo:nil
                                            repeats:YES];
    [progressBar startAnimation: self];
}

-(void)checkThem:(NSTimer *)aTimer
{
    count++;
    if(count > 100)
    {
        count = 0;
        [timer invalidate];
    
        timer = NULL;
        [progressBar setDoubleValue:0.0];
        [progressBar stopAnimation: self];
    }
    else
    {
        [progressBar setDoubleValue:(100.0 * count) / 100];
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any crash or crash message. You are trying to debug an app that was compiled with optimizations so the debugger may behave oddly.

Comment: Message: "No known class method for selector 'scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:selector:userInfo:repeats:'

Comment: Ah, figured it out - Disabled "DeBug Executable" in Scheme. Thanks again.

Comment: @Paul If the problem is solved please either answer your own question (totally legal) or delete the question. Don't leave it hanging. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Andy's comment prompted me to check my Scheme config. "DeBug Executable" was enabled. As such, the function wouldn't work after compiling. I then disabled the option. All good after doing so. Sorry for the trouble.